# PHP: Dividing/Multiplying/Rounding, not exact number

Tags: php, math, floating-point-precision

I made a survey page and there I'm reading the number of votes from a DB.
Now I wanted to get the percentage of votes for displaying a "progress bar".

I wrote this funcion to get the percentage:

```
function progress($cur, $max, $round=1) {
    return ($max!=0) ? round(($cur/$max) *100, $round).'%' : '0%';
}
```

This seemed to be working fine, but for some numbers it adds many zeros and a 1 to the correct value.
For example: 3/34 -> 8.800000000000001%. For other values (tested, 1,2,4,6) it's working correctly.

How can I correct this to display 8.8%?

Comment: 3 and 34 works fine for me! Do you have other examples where it don't work for you? (Tested it with 1..50 and max 34 and all works fine!)See:  http://ideone.com/96bKrg

Comment: Hmm, what precision did you set in the php.ini? I set it to 16...

Comment: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3815/4a73zpbh_png.htm (now 3/36)

Comment: Which number did you used for the 8.3 ?

Comment: 3 divided through 36, how I already wrote...

Comment: My final function:

`function progress($cur, $max, $round=1) {

    if($max!=0 && $cur!=0) {
        return (round(($cur/$max)*100,1) == round(($cur/$max)*100)) ? round(($cur/$max) *100).'%' : sprintf("%.1f", ($cur/$max) *100).'%';
    } else return '0%';
}`

Comment: I don't really understand how this code highlighting works xD

Comment: There is now code highlighting in the comments! Put it in your question or something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the sprintf function in PHP:

```
$formattedOutput = sprintf("%.1f",$floatValue);
```

gives you the the $floatValue with one decimal.
see [PHP manual for sprintf](http://php.net/manual/de/function.sprintf.php)